# How to create a link in Wordpress to a file on an local network server

Tags: wordpress, localhost, intranet

I installed Wordpress on my station and its now being used internally for corporate blogging.
I wanted to know if there is a way to create links to servers in our intranet?

For example to access a server resource in windows I use Run->\server-name\folder\file.txt

How can I create a link to such file in Excel (or generally in HTML) that will be opened by Firefox & IE when clicked in Wordpress.

Thanks,

Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking this, the right way to mimic a UNC form (at least in my case) was:

```
<a href="file://///server-name/folder/file.txt">file</a>
```

which is equal to

```
\\server-name\folder\file.txt
```

It works in Firefox (3.6) and IE (8).

We use Windows XP, all stations are in an Active Directory domain, in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

You can either map the servers to virtual hosts on the web server and create links like you would to any external file on the internet.
Or, if you insist, use

```
<a href="file:///path/to/file.html">file</a>
```

in your example:

```
<a href="file:///server-name/folder/file.txt">file</a>
```

Comment: And bear in mind that your mileage may vary depending on which browser you're using and how your network is set up. Firefox, for example, doesn't like file links with UNC paths, from what I remember, and also doesn't support some Windows authentication methods. (Summary: I'm not sure of the details, but make sure to test things in *all* the browsers that might be used!)